# c function returning a pointer to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

i'm trying to create a function that returns a pointer to a struct here is the code:

the struct:

```
struct Nia{
    char NIA[6];
};
```

the function:

```
struct Nia * prueba(){
   struct Nia *nia = malloc(sizeof(struct Nia)*2);
   strcpy(nia[0].NIA,"11111\0");
   strcpy(nia[1].NIA,"11112\0");
   return nia;
 }
```

main function: (it doesn't print anything but it should print 11111)

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   struct Nia *nia = prueba();

   printf("%s\n",nia[0].NIA);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

where is the problem? i think i'm implemententing the pointers to the structs properly, isn't it?

it returns a segmentation fault actually.

thanks in advance!

Comment: nia[0].NIA  or you mean nia->NIA[0]?

Comment: This works on my system. Having an explicit `\0` in the string is unusual [and _not_ recommended] but is _not_ `UB`. The `strcpy` will stop at _it_ even though the source string looks like: `"11111\0\0"`, so only 5 chars + EOS will be copied

Comment: Runs clean here as well, and no complaints from [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code you presented, but although it is sufficiently minimal, it is not a [mcve] because it is not *complete* (we will leave aside *verifiable* for a moment, because you cannot rely on verifying UB, which most certainly is occurring here).  Completeness requires presenting one or more complete translation units.

Comment: You're not showing your `#include` statements. I had to add some. You may have warnings that you're ignoring. Without a prototype, `malloc` might be interpreted as an `int` return and that would be bad on a 64 bit machine.  Be sure to `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` and do `cc -Wall`

Comment: My best guess is that the two functions presented see incompatible declarations of `struct Nia`.

Comment: It's possible that `malloc` is failing, since its return value is not checked.

Comment: My bet is with @CraigEstey. The problem is the missing `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: yes it is quite curious because i have tested it on codechef.com/ide and it works like a charm

Comment: By the way i am using netbeans and yes i have all the includes required, it is very strange

Comment: On what system is it failing with what configuration? (i.e.) What OS, compiler, options, etc? Also, put it all in a single file and post that here. I've code reviewed it [and tested] and it seems fine.

Comment: Netbeans [as in Java]? Dude. Time to "man up" and go fully to C :-). Obviously, suspicious. More seriously, can you build with optimization off (e.g. `-O0` and `-g`) and run under a debugger (e.g. `gdb`)? You can step the program and examine values and `gdb` will catch the line number of the segfault. Or, run under `valgrind`

Comment: @CraigEstey For completeness sake, on what environment did you test it without trouble?

Comment: @Mast Linux, fedora 22, gcc 5.3.1, an x86 64 bit desktop with 4 cores [with hyperthreading]. Using _no_ optimization [or with `-O2` makes no difference]. `cc -o nia nia.c ; ./nia` and my `nia.c` looks like ocket8888's

Comment: Please add `if(nia  == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n"); exit(1); }` inside `prueba` function.

Comment: I am using netbeans in a mac os and here is the run of the program:

Comment: cd '/Users/mariomoliner/Desktop/Programación/P2/CppApplication_1'
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/cppapplication_1
make[2]: `dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/cppapplication_1' is up to date.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 108ms)

Comment: the output: 

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 10ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms

Comment: as you can see it doesn't print the expected 11111 and now there is not segmentation fault by the way

Comment: @M.Moliner I hope you're not expecting anyone to read that. If it's important, put it in the question and format it properly. That said, I noticed a "cppapplication" bit in there. Compile my code as C, not C++, you'll notice it works. **C and C++ are _not_ the same language**, so you should update your tags if you want help with C++, not C.

Comment: @ocket8888 no thats the name of the project but it is actually in c, i guess i must be a netbeans error because it works for everybody except me

Comment: @M.Moliner Why are you complicating things with `nia[0].NIA` ? There is also `(*nia).NIA` which is the same, but more simple will be `nia->NIA`  =>> [DEMO](http://ideone.com/wAN1Eh)

Comment: @M.Moliner I just ran it on netbeans and it went fine, I think there might be a problem with your nb install

Answer (score 1):

I compiled and ran the following test.c file on Linux Mint 64 bit using `gcc -o test test.c -Wall`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Nia{
    char NIA[6];
};

struct Nia * prueba(){
   struct Nia *nia = malloc(sizeof(struct Nia)*2);
   strcpy(nia[0].NIA,"11111\0");
   strcpy(nia[1].NIA,"11112\0");
   return nia;
 }

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   struct Nia *nia = prueba();

   printf("%s\n",nia[0].NIA);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

it outputs `11111`, and compiles without complaint. Honestly, even if I omit the `include`d headers, it'll run, albiet with warnings, but your system may be different, so just include them and you should be fine.

Of course, having thought about this some more, this can be problematic if you're using **C++** not **C**, which **are not the same language**. You see,  `g++` will have a problem with you assigning the `void*` value that `malloc()` returns to a symbol of type `Nia*`, whereas `gcc` is happy to make the conversion for you. A different C++ compiler, which you might be using, may allow you to compile it, but a `void` has no members, so the `NIA` member may not have been initialized, which results in a segfault when you try to print it.
To be absolutely sure, use a debugger and find where the memory access violation occurs.

UPDATE: just ran this in Netbeans on the same system, went fine.

Comment: For completeness, add `#include <stdio.h>` and there should be _no_ warnings.

Comment: Yeah, and actually `strcpy` is from `string.h`, not `stdlib.h` :P

Comment: It's in mine, too. I forgot when I wrote the comment